# mediate() vs lavaan, missing path coefficients, 2SLS does not resolve

Tags: r, interpretation, mediation, 2sls, path-model

Doing a straightforward mediation analysis, a => b => c (indirect effect) and a => c (direct effect).

If I do this in `mediation::mediate()`, I get

               `Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME            0.02020     -0.00349      0.04934    0.10
ADE            -0.10003     -0.17762     -0.01430    0.02
Total Effect   -0.07984     -0.15468      0.00584    0.06`

Notice this gives me the direct effect a => c (ADE) and an indirect effect a => b => c (ACME), but does not break out a => b and b => c effects.

In contrast, when I use `lavaan`, I get 

             `lhs op            rhs    label    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower
1          c  ~  a        c -0.101 0.041 -2.465  0.014   -0.182
2          b  ~  a        a  0.260 0.064  4.065  0.000    0.135
3          c  ~  b        b  0.080 0.045  1.776  0.076   -0.008
4          c ~~  c           0.072 0.007  9.644  0.000    0.058
5          b ~~  b           0.191 0.020  9.644  0.000    0.152
6          a ~~  a           0.250 0.000     NA     NA    0.250
7       indirect :=            a*b indirect  0.021 0.013  1.628  0.104   -0.004
8         direct :=              c   direct -0.101 0.041 -2.465  0.014   -0.182
9          total :=        c+(a*b)    total -0.081 0.040 -2.026  0.043   -0.159`

The direct, indirect, and total effects match up very well between packages. However, I'd like to get the path coefficients in `mediation::mediate` like I do in `lavaan`. Finding those is my question.

I tried a 2SLS approach, but I don't get the right values. If I do a regression `bOnA <- lm( b ~ a )` where a is a binary factor treatment variable and  b is a continuous variable, then I get `lavaan`'s coefficient  (.26) **when I don't standardize anything and include the intercept**. I assume that for the 2nd stage I should use `b <- predict(bOnA, type="response")` and `cOnB <- lm( c ~ b )` but I can't seem to get a coefficient from the 2nd stage model cOnB that has a coefficient matching `lavaan`.

Interestingly, if I divide the `mediate()` indirect effect by .26, I get .077, which is basically `lavaan`'s output. So it seem that things are correct up to that point.

I've tried variations of the 2nd stage model with centering, standardizing, and removing the intercept to no avail.

My goal is to get this working for a simple case, because I want to use `mediate()` for more complex models than `lavaan` can handle.

Answer (score 0):

This was a conceptual error on my part. One can obtain the `lavaan` coefficients using `lm` with two models:

`bOnA <- lm ( b ~ a )
cOnAandB <- lm ( c ~ a + b)`

Notice the difference between `cOnAandB` and `cOnB`. The coefficient for `b` obtained from `cOnAandB` matches `lavaan` exactly.